# Magento translate.csv file not loading

Tags: php, magento, csv, translation

I created a new package/theme/skin from scratch in Magento 1.9.1.

The theme and skin load fine. I tried adding translations and cannot get them to load. All cache settings are disabled.

I've added the CSV file here:

`/app/design/frontend/{my_package}/{my_theme}/locale/en_US/translate.csv`

translate.csv:

```
"testing123","Translation Worked"
```

header.phtml

```
<?= $this->__('testing123') ?>
```

I added `{my_theme}`, which for me is named "responsive" to the admin at the :

[image: Theme setup]

The result is the header displaying 'testing123' instead of the translated 'Translation Worked'. What have I missed? How do I troubleshoot this?

---

**Update:**

I've also added translate.csv to config.xml (and it still does not work).  However, It DOES work if I move the translate.csv to app/locale/en_US but it DOES NOT work in app/design/frontend/{my_package}/{my_theme}/locale/en_US/translate.csv where I want it. How can I tell it to load from the theme folder?

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyModule_Templates>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyModule_Templates>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <MyModule_Templates>
                    <files>
                        <default>translate.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </MyModule_Templates>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <page>
            <layouts>
                <mymodule_default translate="label">
                    <label>MyModule Default Layout</label>
                    <template>page/default.phtml</template>
                    <layout_handle>mymodule_default</layout_handle>
                </mymodule_default>
            </layouts>
        </page>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems, You forgot to add translate.csv to your module's config.xml. 
Please take a look. 
http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-your-own-translations-to-custom-modules/

Comment: I've added it, see updated answer. It still is not working. It DOES work if I move the `translate.csv` to `app/locale/en_US` but it DOES NOT work in `app/design/frontend/{my_package}/{my_theme}/locale/en_US/translate.csv` where I want it. How can I tell it to load from the theme folder?

Comment: Turned out I didn't have the right theme enabled in the admin. Adding it there fixed it.

Comment: @Justin could you expand on your answer?

Comment: In the admin under `System -> Design` I had to click the currently set theme and then select my own custom theme from the drop-down on that page.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I have single default theme per website and don't need adding design changes... However I tried this solution (selecting store/design) and it didn't help to start reading translation files

Answer (score 1):

i struggled with the same problem. Solution for me was to change the translation Source in the Admin Area.

Go to : Configuration -> select your Store view ( new Translation ) -> General -> under "options for localisation" uncheck the box and choose which translation you want to use. Afterwards, the translate.csv gets loaded and the translation works.

Cheers,

moktor